# Get data cursor callback in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How can I set the Matlab GUI data cursor callback for a specific GUI axes?
I was able to [add the data cursor icon in GUI toolbar](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/07/22/matlab-basics-adding-a-toolbar-to-a-gui/). I can selected 3D point on the plotted data, but I need to add more info in the data cursor text and also do some other stuff with the coordinates it is getting.

I tried to follow "[How to add additional info to the data cursor?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68079-how-to-add-additional-info-to-the-data-cursor)", but doesn't work for GUI.

GUI axes are not figures, so I'm getting this error:

`Error using datacursormode (line 149)
Invalid figure handle`

I need the same here, but for GUI axes (figures?):

```matlab
function test_main
% Plots graph and sets up a custom data tip update function
fig = figure('DeleteFcn','doc datacursormode');
X = 0:60;
t = (X)*0.02;
Y = sin(-16*t);
plot(X,Y)
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig); % tried here "handles.MyFigHandle"
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',{@myupdatefcn,t})

function txt = myupdatefcn(~,event_obj,t)
% Customizes text of data tips
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
I = get(event_obj, 'DataIndex');
txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1))],...
       ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2))],...
       ['I: ',num2str(I)],...
       ['T: ',num2str(t(I))]};
```

For now I can get only the default datacursor behavior, like this image:
[image]

Comment: It seems that datacursormode only supports figure handle. From my understanding, it looks that the data cursor behavior is common to all axes on the figure.

Comment: There must be a way. It shows the selected point as expected, I just don't know how to set its callback so I can do my stuff.

Comment: You can try use `hggetbehavior`, as described [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle-graphics-behavior), or use the file exchange [dualcursor](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2875-dualcursor), that support custom functions inside a GUI, up to its description

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've not found any difference between the use of the `data cursor` in a GUI and in a figure.

Re-using part of your code, I've created a GUI in which a `checkbox` enable / disable the `datacursormode`.

The GUI contains two `axes` in which two lines and a 3D surface are plotted respectively.

Also three `radiobuttons` control the string that will be printed in the textbox generated when the `datacursormode` is enabled.

The tags of the GUI are the folowing:

- left `axes`: `axes_2d`
- right `axes`: `axes_3d`
- left `pushbutton`: `pushbutton_2d`
- right `pushbutton`: `pushbutton_3d`
- `checkbox`: `checkbox_enable_dc`
- left `radiobutton`: `radiobutton1`
- middle `radiobutton`: `radiobutton2`
- righ `radiobutton`: `radiobutton3`

The GUI works this way:

- the `pushbuttons` plot in the axes and enable the `checkbox`
- the `checkbox` enable / disable the `datacursormode`
- by default, the left `radiobutton` is selected and sets the *default string*
- the other two `radiobutton` set a different string

Based on the selected `radiobutton`, the first line of the string in the textbox will be either:

- DEFAULT STRING
- STRING OPTION ONE
- STRING OPTION TWO

the string to be written in the textbox is created in your `myupdatefcn` that has been modified to handle the options selected by the `radiobutton`.

Notice: in order not to limit the modification to your version of the `myupdatefcn` function, I've hard coded the `t` array.

This is the `.m` file of the GUI:

```
function varargout = gui_datacursormode(varargin)
% GUI_DATACURSORMODE MATLAB code for gui_datacursormode.fig
%      GUI_DATACURSORMODE, by itself, creates a new GUI_DATACURSORMODE or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = GUI_DATACURSORMODE returns the handle to a new GUI_DATACURSORMODE or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      GUI_DATACURSORMODE('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in GUI_DATACURSORMODE.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      GUI_DATACURSORMODE('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUI_DATACURSORMODE or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before gui_datacursormode_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to gui_datacursormode_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help gui_datacursormode

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 02-Apr-2017 17:45:45

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @gui_datacursormode_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @gui_datacursormode_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before gui_datacursormode is made visible.
function gui_datacursormode_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to gui_datacursormode (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for gui_datacursormode
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes gui_datacursormode wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = gui_datacursormode_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton_2d.
function pushbutton_2d_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton_2d (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Plot two lines in the first axes
t=0:.1:2*pi;
plot(handles.axes_2d,t,sin(t),'r');
hold(handles.axes_2d,'on')
plot(handles.axes_2d,t,cos(t),'b');
% Enable the checkbox that will set datacorsormode on
handles.checkbox_enable_dc.Enable='on';


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton_3d.
function pushbutton_3d_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton_3d (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Plot a 3D graph in the second axes
axes(handles.axes_3d);
peaks

% Enable the checkbox that will set datacorsormode on
handles.checkbox_enable_dc.Enable='on';


function txt = myupdatefcn(~,event_obj,t)
% Customizes text of data tips

% Get the handles of the GUI to access to the radiobuttons
my_guidata=guidata(gcf);
% Define the additional string to be written
if(my_guidata.radiobutton1.Value)
   str='DEFAULT STRING ';
elseif(my_guidata.radiobutton2.Value)
   str='STRING OPTION ONE ';
else
   str='STRING OPTION TWO ';
end

% Get the datacursor data
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
I = get(event_obj, 'DataIndex');
% Create the whole string to be written
txt = {[str], ...
       ['X: ',num2str(pos(1))],...
       ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2))],...
       ['I: ',num2str(I)],...
       ['T: ',num2str(t(I))]}


% --- Executes on button press in checkbox_enable_dc.
function checkbox_enable_dc_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to checkbox_enable_dc (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% If the checkbox is set
if(hObject.Value)
   %  enable the radiobuttons that control the string to be written
   handles.radiobutton1.Enable='on';
   handles.radiobutton1.Value=1;
   handles.radiobutton2.Enable='on';
   handles.radiobutton3.Enable='on';
   % Create the datacursormode object
   dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf)
   t=rand(1,10000);
   set(dcm_obj,'DisplayStyle','datatip',...
      'SnapToDataVertex','off','Enable','on', ...
      'UpdateFcn',{@myupdatefcn,t})
else
   % If the checkbox is not set, disable the datacursormode
   datacursormode 'off'
end


% --- Executes on button press in radiobutton1.
function radiobutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of radiobutton1

% Toggle the other radiobuttons
handles.radiobutton2.Value=0
handles.radiobutton3.Value=0

% --- Executes on button press in radiobutton1.
function radiobutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of radiobutton1

% Toggle the other radiobuttons
handles.radiobutton1.Value=0
handles.radiobutton3.Value=0


% --- Executes on button press in radiobutton1.
function radiobutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of radiobutton1

% Toggle the other radiobuttons
handles.radiobutton1.Value=0
handles.radiobutton2.Value=0
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'